# How to configure properly an HTTP request using MS Flows

Tags: ms-office, netsuite

I was wondering if someone can help me configuring an HTTP action in Microsoft Flows.

I have built a flow in Microsoft Flows where every time a specific person approves a request from someone in company then I want to create a new entry (record) in NetSuite for a specific record type.

If I do this using Excel is working fine. (There is a script XMLEndopoint in Netsuite where enables us to post data in XML Format)).

When I try to do this using Flows I get 405 method not allowed.

[ScreenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLnXx.jpg)

This is the whole HTTP action.

[ScreenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO5Se.jpg)

I quite new with the Flows.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference and maybe this could help other users.

I managed to fix the error.
I simply add User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 and the flow worked.

Thanks.